# Standalone web server (PHP, MySQL) for Mac

Tags: php, mysql, apache, webserver

I have to work at client's office on a Mac (I'm a PC user) and I can't install anything.
I need a local web server to develop the app. Is there anything like http://www.server2go-web.de/download/download.html but for a Mac? Just so I can download it unpack it and run to have a standalone, non installbale, local web server (Apache, PHP, MySQL).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this blog post about running a lamp server of USB](http://developmentseed.org/blog/2007/aug/03/getting-web-server-run-usb-drive)...

and this: http://www.isaacsu.com/wilt/articles/portable-mamp-or-apache-php-webserver-on-mac-os-x

Comment: "Will MAMP work if the MAMP folder is not located in the Applications directory?

No. In order to work properly the MAMP folder has to be located in the Applications folder." http://www.mamp.info/en/documentation/faq.html#q8

Comment: Yep...just realized that, sorry!

Comment: I think you said something about this before editing your answer http://www.isaacsu.com/wilt/articles/portable-mamp-or-apache-php-webserver-on-mac-os-x I used this one and it seems to work without MySQL though :/

Comment: yeah i changed it because i thought it was a more thorough article...i will put it back in there for future reference

Comment: Both links are broken now, hence a very useless answer.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you're able to install xampp in a portable manner (go for the drive-less install option), just run the setup script when you've copied the installation to where you want it to be.

http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html